# How do I find the underlying cause of a Direct Line error reported at dev.botframework.com

Tags: node.js, botframework

We're using the Direct Line 3.0 API to performance test our Microsoft Bot Framework bots that are written in NodeJS. Regardless of load, we get intermittent timeouts in our harness while waiting for activities we expect to come back. These coincide with issues being reported for the bot at dev.botframework.com. They look like this:
[image: Screen shot of errors]

That message doesn't make it clear what error has been experienced sending a message to us.

Our server-side and client-side are not reporting any errors, as far as I can tell, we are always responding with 20x statuses, and I can only assume the error is happening somewhere between the bot framework and our services. How can I find out what error is causing the error sending the message, or what status code it thinks it has received?

Comment: Please do not use the direct line for load testing. How to load test is outlined in this blog post: https://blog.botframework.com/2017/06/19/Load-Testing-A-Bot/

Comment: Do you have AppInsights setup for this bot?  It can be helpful when trying to diagnose problems.

Comment: We couldn't use the approach in that blog article due to [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/issues/258#issuecomment-319167680) but have a workaround for that now. However... I would actually like to understand how well Direct Line itself works under load, given that's what we'll be using for web chat implementations. Are there published benchmarks?

Comment: For this type of question, open an issue on Microsoft/BotBuilder repo on GitHub.